# Connect object in .xib to existing IBAction

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, interface-builder, ibaction

I am quite new to iOS Programming.

This is my question:

I want to connect a new object to an existing IBAction method. For example, I want to buttons to perform the same function.

But when I "control-drag" it, it will always ask me to insert as a new method. How can I add to the existing one instead of creating a new one?

Snapshot in XCode
[image: Snapshot in XCode]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `xib` editor, you can see the `File's Owner`. Just right click the button to see the black popup as shown in the image below. Then drag the *empty* dot to the `File's Owner` tab and release the drag action. You'll see a popup of all existing `IBAction`s. Select the one you want and it'll be added as a selector to your button. You can do this for as many buttons as you want.

[image]