# How do I let the user see the value of a UISlider?

Tags: ios, xcode

I added a UISlider in interface builder in my iOS application. Can I make it so that the user can see the value of a UISlider while he/she is altering it?

Is there an interface builder setting I can change to easily implement this, or must I implement an IBAction that alters a UILabel on the screen based on the slider's value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect the `UISlider`'s `valueChanged` selector to your custom `IBAction` and set some `UILabel`'s value in that method

Comment: Thanks, I can associate an IBAction to that selector. However, is there a way to do this through the interface builder?

Comment: Ofcourse...take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554121/connect-object-in-xib-to-existing-ibaction/9554230#9554230) with images

Comment: Oh, ok thanks. I meant setting the slider to change directly in the interface builder. However, your method certainly works. Thanks!

Comment: you can set a default value but not slide the slider in your `xib` like you would in the app!

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. You can set an outlet of type

```
    IBOutlet UISlider *slider
```

in your view controller, then bind it to the slider. Then the value of the slider is always accessible through the slider.value property, even in other methods.